# Requiring expression in Solidity

Tags: ethereum, solidity

So I have tried both of these in remix and one errors and the other does not and I'm trying to figure out why.

This is my first case -

```
mapping(address => uint) public balanceReceived;

function withdrawMoney(address _to, uint _amount) payable public {
   require(balanceReceived[msg.sender] - _amount > 0, "You do not have the funds");
}
```

This produces the error -

```
transact to ExceptionExample.withdrawMoney errored: VM error: revert.

revert
    The transaction has been reverted to the initial state.
Note: The called function should be payable if you send value and the value you send should be less than your current balance.
Debug the transaction to get more information.
```

However, the below works -

```
function withdrawMoney(address _to, uint _amount) payable public {
   require(balanceReceived[msg.sender] > _amount, "You do not have the funds");
}
```

This produces the error -

```
    transact to ExceptionExample.withdrawMoney errored: VM error: revert.

revert
    The transaction has been reverted to the initial state.
Reason provided by the contract: "You do not have sufficient funds".
Debug the transaction to get more information.
```

In this case the require actually triggered.

I would expect both of these expressions to be identical, but the behaviour is different - why?

Comment: If you can create a minimum source code that is enough to reproduce, I can help.

Answer (score 0):

```
balanceReceived[msg.sender] - _amount
```

This subtraction in the first snippet causes an [integer underflow](https://swcregistry.io/docs/SWC-101) if `_amount` is larger than `balanceReceived[msg.sender]`.

Since Solidity 0.8.0, an exception is thrown if integer underflow or overflow would happen. And the uncaught exception results in the revert without any custom error message.

**Solution:** Use the second snippet, which can't cause integer underflow.

```
require(balanceReceived[msg.sender] > _amount, "You do not have the funds");
```

---

I'm not sure if this is on purpose, but it's unusual that your condition only allows the withdraw amount to be larger than the balance - not "larger or equal". So if you had balance of `1000000000000000000` (1 token with 18 decimals), you would only be able to withdraw `999999999999999999` (little less than the 1 full token) because of the current condition `balanceReceived[msg.sender] > _amount`.

If you changed the condition to "larger or equal" (`balanceReceived[msg.sender] >= _amount`), you would be able to withdraw the full balance.